# sine function is not closed

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I have searched on MSE but did not find any clear solution for this problem. I have found in a blog that

sin map from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ (or $[-1,1]$) is not closed. He/She claimed that

The set $F=\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [2n\pi + \frac{1}{n+1},2n\pi + \pi – \frac{1}{n+1}]$ is closed, but $f(F)=(0,1]$

Can someone explain this to me as I think $F$ is not closed in this representation? Is this true?

Special thanks go to Jean-Pierre Merx and [here is the question](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuous-maps-that-are-not-closed-or-not-open/)

Comment: The complement of $F$ is a union of (disjoint) open intervals. So the complement is open meaning that $F$ is closed.

Comment: @RobArthan The complement of union shall be the intersection. Could write up what you meant?

Comment: @BadrAlharbi The complement is indeed a union of open intervals as Rob Arthan pointed out. You could try to draw them on a piece of paper to visualize where those intervals are located.

Comment: @BadrAlharbi Your thought that the complement of union shall be an intersection is correct by De Morgan's Law, but it's equivalent as a union of disjoint open intervals **in this case**.

Comment: @RobArthan@Mysterium I really appreciate your comments. I finally have discovered what you guys said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your definition of $F$, we have
$$\Bbb R\setminus F=(-\infty,1)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}((2n+1)\pi-\frac{1}{n+1},(2n+2)\pi+\frac{1}{n+1})$$
Since the complement of $F$ is a union of open intervals (open in $\Bbb R$), $F$ is closed, but on those intervals, $\sin(F)$ runs from $0$ (exclusive) to $1$ (inclusive), i.e., $(0,1]$. This is clearly NOT closed in $\Bbb R$ **equipped with the Euclidean topology**. This proves the claim.

---

I'm assuming that $\Bbb N$ contains $0$.